# Cherrypy logingg POST body

Tags: python, logging, cherrypy

I'am using default cherrypy logger.
I have log every access request to my server. For GET request i have full info, like

```
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Jul/2021:16:10:28] "GET /test/?contract_id=228322 HTTP/1.0" 200 33
```

But for POST request i can't log query params or body.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Jul/2021:13:21:03] "POST /test HTTP/1.0" 201 169
```

So how can i log POST query's body?

Comment: In addition to the previous answer:
user agent can be empty. And You can accidentally raise KeyError

Answer (score 1):

You can create tool like

```
def response_logging():
    cherrypy.log.access_log.info(
        '[{time}] {ip} "{user_agent}" {request_line} "{query_params}" "{body}" "{status}" {response}'.format(
            time=datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y:%H:%M:%S"),
            ip=cherrypy.request.remote.ip,
            user_agent=cherrypy.request.headers["User-Agent"],
            request_line=cherrypy.request.request_line,
            query_params=cherrypy.request.body.request_params or "",
            body=cherrypy.request.json if hasattr(cherrypy.request, "json") else "",
            status=cherrypy.response.status,
            response=cherrypy.response.body
        )
    )


cherrypy.tools.response_logging = cherrypy.Tool('on_end_request', response_logging)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(cherrypy.request.params) # Prints params on querystring
print(cherrypy.request.headers) # Prints received headers on request
print(cherrypy.request.body) # Prints Body received
```